# PetaPoco INSERT with @ in the string

Tags: t-sql, petapoco

I want to Execute a line of SQL which looks like this:

```
conn.Open();
var db = new PetaPoco.Database(conn);
var sql = "INSERT INTO FOO (name) VALUES ( 'foo@bar.com')";
var response = db.Execute(sql);
```

The problem is that PetaPoco thinks @bar is a parameter.  Is there a way to tell it not to treat any @'s specially?   My super lame work around was  to replace "@" with "at".  I live with this shame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use two @ characters to escape it. I think this should work:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO FOO (name) VALUES ( 'foo@@bar.com')"
```

Answer (score 5):

"You are doing it wrong"™

To avoid SQL Injection attacks, and other minuances concatenting strings, you should use parameters:

```
var response = db.Execute("INSERT INTO FOO (name) VALUES (@0)", "foo@bar.com");
```

Wrong way, but works at least:

```
var response = db.Execute("INSERT INTO FOO (name) VALUES ('foo@@bar.com')",
```